# Regex catch string between two strings, multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I´m working on a *.po file, I´m trying to catch all the text between `msgid ""` and `msgstr ""`, not really lucky, never more than one line:

```
msgid ""
"%s asdfgh asdsfgf asdfg %s even if you "
"asdfgdh sentences with no sense. We are not asking  translate "
"Shakespeare's %s Hamlet %s !. %s testing regex %s "
"don't require specific industry knowledge. enjoying "
msgstr ""
```

What I´ve tried:

```
var myArray = fileContent.match(/msgid ([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g);
```

Thanks for your help, I´m not really good with regex :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to extract all of that text:

```
var match = text.replace(/msgid ""([\s\S]*?)msgstr ""/, "$1");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bqk79/

The `[\s\S]` is a character class that will match any character including line breaks, so `[\s\S]*?` will match any number of any character.  In other languages you could use the `s` or `DOTALL` flag to make `.` match line breaks, but Javascript does not support this.

Note that you regex doesn't make any mention of single quotes, but if you need to be able to match between `msgid ''` and `msgstr ''` as well you can use the following:

```
var match = text.replace(/msgid (['"]{2})([\s\S]*?)msgstr \1/, "$2");
```

Comment: Simply My two days search, ends here.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this pattern:

```
/msgid (["']{2})\n([\s\S]*?)\nmsgstr \1/
```

The result is in the second capturing group, but you can make more simple with:

```
/msgid ["']{2}\n([\s\S]*?)\nmsgstr /
```

in the first capturing group

Comment: `s` flag does not exist in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that the question specifically asks for a regular expression, but you should consider using string split instead if you can.

Here is a ready-made function:

```
function extractTextBetween(subject, start, end) {
    try{
        return subject.split(start)[1].split(end)[0];
    } catch(e){
        console.log("Exception when extracting text", e);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b33hdh9b/3/

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps try this regex?

```
msgid ""((?:.|[\n\r])+)msgstr ""
```

`((?:.|[\n\r])+)` this is your catching group;

`(?:.|[\n\r])+` This enables the match of `.` or `[\n\r]` multiple times, the `\n\r` are for newlines and carriage returns.

[Tested](http://regex101.com/r/nZ6lS9)